# Pimcore 5: stuck in maintenance mode after upgrade from 4.6.2 to 5.0

Tags: php, pimcore

I am trying to upgrade a website from Pimcore 4.6 to 5.0. I have followed the steps in the [migration guide](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.0.x/Installation_and_Upgrade/Updating_Pimcore/Upgrade_from_4_to_5/index.html) the best I could.

The system seems stuck in [Maintenance mode](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.0.x/Extending_Pimcore/Maintenance_Mode.html), unlike previous versions I cannot find the file maintenance.php to delete, the admin interface is not accessible and there are no messages in the logs.

I tried following the code path. The front controller web/app.php is called, and the following code in pimcore/config/kernel.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel(Config::getEnvironment(), $debug);
Pimcore::setKernel($kernel);
$kernel->boot();
```

This is where I hit a dead end, I cannot find setKernel(), maybe it is a magic setter? What can I do to debug this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You actually should have a setKernel static method in your Pimcore Class (pimcore/lib/Pimcore.php). This does hint to a partially incomplete Update. What might make sense is to download the zip of the pimcore 5, unpack it into a separate folder and use a diff tool to compare the diferences in the Pimcore core files.

If you can't find a maintenance.php in var/config folder, that would also indicate that system isn't really in maintenance mode, but rather that something is broken somewhere else - as it seems to be the case.

Did you also look into PHP logs (/var/log/php), Apache logs (/var/log/apache) or nginx logs (/var/log/nginx)?